# How exactly to save and retrieve last seen message timestamp - plist or NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, plist, appdelegate

I have two UIViewControllers. In the FirstViewController, I download the groupsInfo data from the firebase and show the details(groupName,lastMessage) in the UITableView and have one more label "lastMessageTime"(this information will come from SecondViewController).Once I tap the UITableView cell, it goes to the detail page SecondViewController, here I download the messageInfo based on the tapped groupID. When I leave the SecondViewController, I want to store the last message time for that particular groupID in commonplace (either plist or NSUserDefaults) and retrieve the information in the FirstViewController or in some other ViewController(later stage). The saved data shouldn't get deleted and also I should be able to update(in case value already exist for particulat key) "lastMessageTime" for any particular groupID whenever there is new message.

Below is code I tried, but not sure if this is the best approach. Would be great if you can tell me the best approach to deal this requirement effectively.

SecondViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  [self updateLastMessageSeenTime:groupID];
}

-(void)updateLastMessageSeenTime:(NSString*)groupID
{
  FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot = [self.messageArray lastObject];
  NSMutableDictionary *lastSeenMessageTime = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  NSString *lastMessageTime = snapshot.value[@"timeStamp"];
  [lastSeenMessageTime setValue:lastMessageTime forKey:groupID];
  NSUserDefaults *lastSeenMessageTimeUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [lastSeenMessageTimeUserDefaults setObject:lastSeenMessageTime forKey:@"lastMessageTimeArrayKey"];
  [lastSeenMessageTimeUserDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Above method erases all the previous data. For Example, If visited the SecondViewController twice each for different groupID, previous groupID's lastMessageTime is removed and replaced with the new groupID's.

Comment: Basically `NSUserDefaults` is the wrong place to share data between view controllers. The recommended ways are segues, callback blocks, the protocol/delegate pattern or notifications.

Comment: Basically, I don't want to share data between two view controllers, but to store some information permanently and retrieve the data/information for the later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the dictionary from `NSUserDefaults` first and if it doesn't exist then `init` a new one. Try this.

```
-(void)updateLastMessageSeenTime:(NSString*)groupID
{
  FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot = [self.messageArray lastObject];
  NSUserDefaults *lastSeenMessageTimeUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *key = @"lastMessageTimeArrayKey";

  NSMutableDictionary *lastSeenMessageTime = [[lastSeenMessageTimeUserDefaults objectForKey: key] mutableCopy];
  if (!lastSeenMessageTime) {
    lastSeenMessageTime = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  }
  NSString *lastMessageTime = snapshot.value[@"timeStamp"];
  [lastSeenMessageTime setValue:lastMessageTime forKey:groupID];
  NSUserDefaults *lastSeenMessageTimeUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [lastSeenMessageTimeUserDefaults setObject:lastSeenMessageTime forKey: key];
  [lastSeenMessageTimeUserDefaults synchronize];
}
```